# Embed MS Excel in SWF / Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, flash, asp.net-mvc-3, excel, embed

For a project requirement, I want to make available editing of an excel file through browser.
The only possible ways that I could think of was by embedding the excel file either in Flash or Silverlight. I am building my project on asp.net mvc3 c#.

I wanted to know that is there a way by which this could be achieved? 
I shall be happy to start an open source project is need be so that people who are interested can collaborate together.

Any pointer would be great.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well on Windows Live Skydrive there is an Silverlight Excel app, but that requires windows live accounts... There are other controls out there I'm sure, just most will cost something.